# How to configure Telerik Extension on ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: telerik, telerik-mvc

I am unable to configure Telerik Extension for ASP NET MVC 4 on my machine. However all source codes and configurations are given only for MVC 3.

Can anyone help me out of this problem? Step by step procedures are welcome.

Thanking you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

did you tried to instal using nuGet: 
Install-Package TelerikMvcExtensions